# Jenkins skip stage when Boolean parameter is false

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to skip stage in jenkins when Boolean parameter condition API1, API2, API3 is false. Tried below. i got error Not a valid stage section definition: "if (params.API1== false || params.API2 == false || params.API3== false )

```
    booleanParam(
       name: 'API1',
       defaultValue: false,
    )
    booleanParam(
        name: 'API2',
        defaultValue: false,
    )
    booleanParam(
        name: 'API3',
        defaultValue: false,
    )
     choice(
        name: 'Env',
        choices: [ 'uat', 'test']
   )
    }
    
    stage ('docker build') {
            if (params.API1 == false || params.API2 == false || params.API3 == false ) {
        agent { xxxx }
        when {
                expression { params.Env == 'uat' || params.Env == 'test' }
            }
            steps 
            {
                unstash 'xxxx'
            script {
                    my script
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your stage would probably look like this:

```
    stage ('docker build') {
        agent { xxxx }
        when {
            beforeAgent true  // don't wait for agent to evaluate conditions
            allOf {
                expression { params.API1 == true || params.API2 == true || params.API3 == true }
                expression { params.Env == 'uat' || params.Env == 'test' }
            }
        }
        steps 
        {
            unstash 'xxxx'
            script {
                    my script
            }
        }
    }
```